# template operators fail seemingly on ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, header, operators

This is not a duplicate. I've checked lots of answers, the FAQ and else. Nothing of that told me news. Here is the simplified code. It's the minimum to get and explain the error.

```
/*** Polynomial.hpp ********************************************************/

namespace Modulus
{
// Forward declaration of the types and non-inline template friend functions.

template <typename T>
    class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
    Polynomial<T>  operator +
        (Polynomial<T> const & p,
         Polynomial<T> const & q);
}

namespace Modulus
{

template <typename T>
class Polynomial
{
public:
    Polynomial() { }

    // [!] when you comment this in, you get the error.
    //Polynomial      operator +      () const { return *this; }

    friend Polynomial operator + <> (Polynomial const & p,
                                     Polynomial const & q);
};

} // namespace

// Template: include .cpp file.
   //#include "Polynomial.cpp"
///^ It is commented out, for compiling in one file.


/*** Polynomial.cpp ********************************************************/

namespace Modulus
{

template <typename T>
Polynomial<T>
    operator + (Polynomial<T> const & p,
                Polynomial<T> const & q)
{
    return Polynomial<T>();
}

} // namespace


/*** main.cpp **************************************************************/


//#include "Polynomial.hpp"

using namespace Modulus;

int main()
{
    Polynomial<int> p;
    p + p;
    return 0;
}
```

When I comment the line under `[!]` in, the error I get is `friends can only be classes or functions` (Clang++) or `declaration of ‘operator+’ as non-function` (g++).

For me, it seems the compilers mistake the two operators. As far as I've learned the operator overloading stuff, the unary and binary operators are completely independent and can be **uniquely distinguished by their number of arguments**.

So why does the error occur? Making the unary operator a friend using the standard practice, makes the code compile fine on both compilers.

Comment: Interesting. If you put the unary `operator+` below the friend declaration of the binary one, both gcc and clang compile it without complaint, if you put it above, you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare something in a scope, it hides delcarations of the same name in any wider scope. Here, the declaration of the member `operator+` hides that of the non-member. So the `friend` declaration refers to the member, not the non-member, hence the error.

You'll need to qualify the name if you want to refer to both in the same scope:

```
Polynomial      operator +      () const { return *this; }

friend Polynomial Modulus::operator + <> (Polynomial const & p, Polynomial const & q);
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It appears that the OP's real header includes the source file at the bottom.

Comment: @chris: So it does. That's nasty.

Comment: It is common enough, but typically, the extension would be something other than cpp. Doesn't libstdc++ use tpp?

Comment: libstdc++ uses `.tcc`. Some editors even recognize that as C++ source file extension (for syntax highlighting, indentation etc.), so it's not a bad way to follow if you want to do things this way.

Comment: Indeed, "nasty" refers to the choice of name (confusing both for my poor old brain, and for automated tools and scripts), not the concept of hiding definitions in a separate include file.